# Construct command with arguments with spaces and multiple commands bash

Tags: arrays, bash, loops, parsing, arguments

Ok I have a script I'm writing in bash for cloud foundry to add services to an organization.

As a part of the requirement the user needs to be able to pass in the services as an argument.  The create service command in CF takes 3 arguments the service name, plan, custom-name.

The arg is passed in like -a "servicename planname customname, nextservice nextplan nextname"

I was thinking that in order to do a double parse on this that I would have to do it like this

-a "servicename; planname; customname, nextservice; nextplan; nextname"

then we call the command to add it cf create-service servicename planname customname

or if it has spaces in the name

cf create-service "servicename" "planname" "customname"

So with that said I have my script working just fine and you can give as many services as you want comma delimited.  But the problem I have is I have one service in our organization that has a space in the service name and a space in the plan name.

So I've been trying to figure out how to build my function to parse through string to build out the command.  I have a feeling I need 2 different for loops one that will parse out the entire string pre comma and then a 2nd for loop to build the command with and if there are any spaces found in the args to wrap them in quotes.

So this is what I have thus far

```
 add_service() {
  if [ -n "${ADDSERVICEID}" ]
    then
      if [ "${ADDSERVICEID}" == "default" ]
        then
          ....Our Default services are here
          echo "The following services are now enabled in your organization"
          cf services
      else
        IFS=","
        for i in "${ADDSERVICEID[@]}"; do
          if [[ $i =~ \ ]]; then
            $i=\"$i\"
          fi
            for i in "${FULLSERVICE[@]}"; do
               $i
              echo "The following services are now enabled in your organization"
              cf services
            done
          done
      fi
  fi
}
```

I'm basically working on the else section as my default section since they're all static work just fine. I'm sure I'm probably over thinking this and the answer is probably staring me right in the face but I'm just having an issue wrapping my head around it.  Also changing the names of the service or plan to not have spaces is not an option for us.

Thank you all for your help and I hope that once we have an answer to this it will help others down the road.

UPDATE:  Ok so its now sort of working.  I can add my services with spaces in their names.  Great.

Now however if I give it more than one service to add it just slams it all together in one statement instead of parsing on the ,

Here is the updated code

```
  else
    IFS=","
    for arg1 in "${ADDSERVICEID[@]}"; do
      IFS=";"
        CREATESERVICE=""
        for arg2 in "${arg1[@]}"; do
          if [[ $arg2 =~ \  ]]
           then
            $arg2=\'\"$arg2\"\'
          fi
          CREATESERVICE+="${arg2}"
          echo ${CREATESERVICE}
          cf create-service ${CREATESERVICE}
          echo "The following services are now enabled in your organization"
          cf services
        done
    done
  fi
```

I only pasted in from the else onward

UPDATE: Duh you gotta remove some quotes no wonder it was picking it all up as one string.  Sigh I think its time for bed

```
else
  IFS=,
  for arg1 in ${ADDSERVICEID[@]}; do
    IFS=";"
      CREATESERVICE=""
      for arg2 in "${arg1[@]}"; do
        if [[ $arg2 =~ \  ]]
         then
          $arg2=\'\"$arg2\"\'
        fi
        CREATESERVICE+=${arg2}
        echo ${CREATESERVICE}
        cf create-service ${CREATESERVICE}

      done
  done
  echo "The following services are now enabled in your organization"
  cf services
fi
```

This now works as it should, it takes the args, if there are spaces in them we wrap the arg in quotes, we parse it on the , and the ; of it so it works like a champ now.

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 0):

This is the final rendition of this portion of the function for now as it is doing what I wanted it to do

```
else
  IFS=,
  for arg1 in ${ADDSERVICEID[@]}; do
    IFS=";"
      CREATESERVICE=""
      for arg2 in "${arg1[@]}"; do
        if [[ $arg2 =~ \  ]]
         then
          $arg2=\'\"$arg2\"\'
        fi
        CREATESERVICE+=${arg2}
        echo ${CREATESERVICE}
        cf create-service ${CREATESERVICE}

      done
  done
  echo "The following services are now enabled in your organization"
  cf services
fi
```